# logback <configuration debug="true"> .... except in Java

Tags: java, logback

Copying directly from the Baeldung website here:

```
To see debug information as Logback processes the configuration, you can turn on debug logging:

<configuration debug="true">
  ...
</configuration>
```

https://www.baeldung.com/logback

Is there any way to do this in Java Config?
If this is in the manual feel free to point me to where I could find it.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the `StatusPrinter`? What was the result in using that class?

Comment: @Progman Interesting, I tried this and it appears to be printing the configuration contained within some logback.xml it found somewhere on the classpath.  However I am setting the logback configuration in Java, so what it prints is not the 'real' configuration.

Comment: Since you are building the configuration in java, what about registering the `OnConsoleStatusListener`?